# function calling

Tags: javascript, jquery

May be a simple question to solve...
On button click I call a function on the include file and parse a function name (b). Why b is not a function ?
I have the following files (only a sample of the issue):

### comum.js

```
function f(b){
    var a = eval(b +'();');
}

function a(v){
    $.ajax({url:'update.aspx',
            data: 'q=5',
            success: function(){
                f(v);
            }   
    });
}
```

### default.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="comum.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#me").click(function(){
            a('b');
        });
    });

    function b(){
        $("#me").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="me" value="click me" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `eval`.

Change this:

```
a('b');
```

To this instead:

```
a(b);
```

And then also:

```
success: function(){
    v();
}
```

Comment: This one seams to work and if I need to pass two functions names like a([b,c]) also tried and it worked. Super

Comment: Cheers, glad it's working. Feel free to accept the answer if that's what you ended up using. :)

Answer (score 1):

While the others are right that it is better to not use `eval` in this situation, you did ask a specific question that hasn't been answered.

> **"Why b is not a function?"**

The reason is that you gave the parameter to the `f()` function the same name as the global `b()` function. So when `b` is eval'd, the `b` parameter that is *"shadowing"* the `b` function is referenced.

```
function f(b){ // <-- Parameter with same name as function.
    var a = eval(b +'();'); // <-- So the eval is a reference right back to the
}                           //       'b' parameter (a string) instead of the
                            //       'b' function.

  // global function b
function b(){
    $("#me").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
```

So as you can see, the `eval()` is executed from the local variable scope, and the first `b` that is found in the scope chain is the same `b` that you passed to eval.

---

All you need to do is change the name of the parameter to something other than `b`.

```
  // ---------v------ different name so we don't shadow the global "b()" function
function f( func ){
    var a = eval( func +'();' );
}
```

So here I changed the parameter to `func`. Now when the string referenced by `func` is eval'd, it will reference the global `b()` function because the parameter is no longer in the way.

---

FYI, another approach would be to access the function directly as a property of `window`, because global variables are automatically added as properties.

```
function f( b ){
    var a = window[ b ]();
}
```

Now you're asking for the `b` function *directly* from the `window` object, instead of evaluating the argument you received as a member of the variable scope chain.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. The value of the local variable *b* is the string "b", so eval resolves it to the local *b*, not the global *b* (ECMA-262 section 10.2.2 applies). Would rather see a reference to *global[b]* than *window[b]* though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but when you call `a` with `'b'` as a parameter, you are passing the character `'b'`, rather than a reference to the function `b`.

To pass a reference to the function `b` to `a`, change `a('b');` to `a(b);`.

Comment: he wants to call b via the eval(); with `eval(b+'();');` for some reason

Comment: Yes... I missed that, but in that case, see Shadow Wizard's answer.

Comment: Actually I pass two or three functions to be called as variable a(['a','b']) and want to keep functions I use in all application apart from the ones the just manipulate page DOM. In this case function b

Comment: @user831513: I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596227/function-calling/6596952#6596952) that explains why the code in your question doesn't work.

Comment: @James: Oddly enough, this answer is actually sort of correct, but for a different reason. When the string `'b'` is eval'd, it is done inside the `f()` function, which has a parameter named `b`, which as it turns out refers back to the original `'b'` string that was passed. So the result is that with or without the `eval`, OP is calling `'b'()`, and a string is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The program ends up with calling `eval('b()')` (in `f()`), but at this point, the function `b()` cannot be found, since it's defined locally in the lambda function (within `$()`).

I guess that you have to define `b()` as global function in order for `eval` to work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass an anonymous function instead of passing the function's name (to parse it using `eval`)?

It would became like this, and it's better.

```
function f(b){
    var a = b();
}

function a(v){
    $.ajax({url:'update.aspx',
        data: 'q=5',
        success: function(){
            f(function() {
                ....
            });
        }   
    });
}
```